# Encrypt the response data in angular 5 project

Tags: php, angular, encryption, angular5

I am working on a php and angular 5 project and I need to know how to encrypt the response that appears in the network tab. Can we encrypt it so the user can't read any response ?

Comment: Why would you want to achieve this? Though it doesn't sound like a SO  question

Comment: If you want to do this to hide the inner workings of your app on the client side then you are approaching the problem wrong. Any logic you execute on the client side can be replicated by the user if they so choose.

Comment: Its not possible completely but you can achieve it partly send sending encrypted text data and decrypting in the browser. But I am unsure how safe it will be even after angular code being minified. Its definitely not a recommended way. Go for https which will send receive encrypted data. But in dev tools it will be visible. I have not heard of any way to achieve that.

Comment: I don't know why people vote negative this question, I think it's a good question that can't be solved, but it's not bad.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I need to encrypt the request and response calls, like if I am using ajax, I need to encrypt what ajax return.

Answer (score 5):

- The server belongs to you. You control the server.
- The browser belongs to your visitor. They control the browser.

It is not possible to provide data to the browser without also providing it to the visitor.

Encryption via HTTPS will secure data from third parties trying to sniff it in transit. This is what encryption on the WWW is most useful for.

If you want to secure it from the visitor then **don't send it to the browser in the first place**. Keep it on the server. Process it there. Associate it with the visitor using a session and/or user account.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I need to encrypt the request and response calls, like if I am using ajax, I need to encrypt what ajax return.

Comment: @am909090 — When the answer is "It is impossible", restating your question isn't going to result in a different answer. Depending on who you are trying to stop reading the data: See one of the two final paragraphs.

Answer (score -1):

You can encrypt browser - server data but you can't ensure the data is 100% invisible by the user client.

If you want to obfuscate the data, you can use [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) to make more difficult data readable. But don't try to encrypt json data thinking user won't be able to read it. Even using asymmetric encryption, you have to send a public key to the browser that can be detected by the user making data readable.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I need to encrypt the request and response calls, like if I am using ajax, I need to encrypt what ajax return.